# Gibbs state and creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian

Let's consider quantum Fermi or Bose gas. Let $a(\xi)$, $a^{\dagger}(\xi)$ are standard annihilation and annihilation operators.  Hamiltonian of system is denoted as
$$
\hat{H} = \int_{R^3} \frac{p^2}{2m} a^{\dagger} (p) a(p) dp,
$$
operator of number of particles is
$$
\hat{N} = \int_{R^3} a^{\dagger} (p) a(p) dp.
$$
Then the operator of thermodynamic equilibrium is
$$
\omega_{\beta, n} = \frac{ e^{-\beta(\hat{H} - \mu \hat{N})} }{Z},
$$
when $\beta$ is inverse temperature, $\mu$ is chemical potential. I would like to calculation the following expressions.
$$
\omega_{\beta, n} (a(p)) = Tr \left( a(p) \omega_{\beta, n} \right) = ?
$$
$$
\omega_{\beta, n} (a^{\dagger}(p)) = Tr \left( a^{\dagger}(p) \omega_{\beta, n} \right) = ?
$$
And in general case polynomials of $a(p_1), a^{\dagger} (p_2) $
$$
\omega_{\beta, n} \left( a^n(p_1) \left( a^{\dagger} \right)^k (p_2) \right) = ?
$$
If I clear understood it's important task in quantum optics. I don't understand how to solve it.

I got that operators $\hat{N}, \hat{H}$  commute, but I don't know how to solve main problem.

Comment: "operators $\hat{N}, \hat{H}, a(\xi), a^{\dagger}(\eta)$  commute with each other."  No they don't

Comment: @mikestone, sorry, I made mistakes. I mean operators  $N, H$ commutative. For $a, a^{\dagger}$  commutative or anti-commutative relations hold with respect Fermi or Bose gas. I'll edit to it. Thank you for your comment

Comment: $a$ and $a^\dagger$, whether Bose or Fermi,  do not commute with either $N$ on $H$. That is why ${\rm Tr}(a \exp\{-\beta H\})=0$.

Comment: @mikestone,  your are right. I edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Wick's theorem in statistical physics. It is explained in the textbook of L. Reichl, 4th edition, appendix D. If I am not wrong, then M. Gaudin was the first formulating it like this in 1960: *Une démonstration simplifiée du théoreme de wick en mécanique statistique*. I think these are good starting points to see what you need to do.

Comment: See also *W.T. Grandy, Jr.Foundations of Statistical Mechanics. Volume I: Equilibrium Theory.1987* appendix G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is already answered in the comments, but it can put more clearly as follows.

Suppose there is a way to label the $p$ states, as $p_1,p_2,\ldots$. Then, the many-body state in the occupation-number representation $|n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots\rangle$ is an eigenstate of both $H,N$, and the density matrix acting on it gives a number. The trace can be broken down as

\begin{equation}
Tr(A\omega)=\sum_{n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots} \frac{\exp\left[\sum_i \beta(p_i^2/2m-\mu)n_{p_i}\right]}{Z} \langle n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots|A|n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots\rangle
\end{equation}

for any operator $A$. Specifically, if $A=a_{p_k},a_{p_k}^\dagger$ for some state $p_k$, then the inner product is 0. The same can also be said if $A=a_{p}^n(a_{p^\prime}^{\dagger})^k$ if $p\neq p^{\prime}$ and $n\neq k$.

Edit: As noted in the comment, the case of non-vanishing expectation value is worth mentioning.
First, note that because $H,N$ are one-body operators, the partition function is a product of one-body partition functions:
\begin{align}
 Z&=\sum_{n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots} e^{-\sum_i\beta(\epsilon_{p_i}-\mu)n_{p_i}}, \quad \epsilon_p=p^2/2m\\
&=\prod_{i}\left(\sum_{n_i} e^{-\beta(\epsilon_{p_i}-\mu)n_{p_i}} \right) = \prod_iZ_i^{(1)}
\end{align}

If $A=a_{p_k}^\dagger a_{p_k}$ is the number operator for state $p_k$, the required expectation value
\begin{align}
Tr(A\omega)&= \sum_{n_{p_1},n_{p_2},\ldots} \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\sum_i \beta(\epsilon_{p_i}-\mu)n_{p_i}}n_{p_k} \\
&= \frac{1}{Z}\prod_{i\neq k}Z_i^{(1)} \times \left( \sum_{n_{p_k}} n_{p_k}e^{-\beta(\epsilon_{p_k}-\mu)n_{p_k}}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{Z^{(1)}_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial(\beta\mu)}{Z^{(1)}_k}
\end{align}

The one-body partition function is easily calculated for fermions ($n_{p_k}=0,1$) or bosons (sum of a geometric series). The result is the Bose/Fermi function.

The average of the $n$th power of the number operator is obtained by taking derivative of $Z_k^{(1)}$ $n$ times.

Comment: +1. This partially answers OP's query. But the cases for which the expectation does not vanish are of great interest (e.g. average occupation number).

Answer (score 1):

There is an identity that is useful when you need to compute commutations with exponentiated operators for boson operators. It is
$$ \exp(\hat{X})\hat{Y}\exp(-\hat{X})=\hat{Y}+[\hat{X},\hat{Y}] +\frac{1}{2!}[\hat{X},[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]]+\frac{1}{3!}[\hat{X},[\hat{X},[\hat{X},\hat{Y}]]] +... $$
So, if you work out the commutators of the ladder operators with the argument of the thermal operator, then you can evaluate the above expression. From it you can obtain the commutator by multiplying on the right by the thermal operators.